# If for every k the interval $[a,ak]$ contains $n$ specials numbers how many special numbers $[az,akz]$ must contain?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, problem-solving

The purpose of my question is to determine if a specific kind of reasoning is true or false.

Let's say that for every positive natural number $a$, there is a at least $n$ "special numbers" in the interval of natural numbers $[a,ak]$ where $k$ is a constant.

Is it true that, by multiplying the boundaries by $z$, the number of "special numbers" in the interval $[az, akz]$ is also multiplied by $z$?

If no, why ? And if yes, what are the conditions on $z$ for this being true ?

Comment: There is an ambiguity in your question: does $n$ depend on $a$ or is it a constant? If it depends on $a$, how so? Is there a lower bound on $n$ for a given value of $a$?

Comment: @CliveNewstead I'm sorry. What I meant is that for every integer $a$ equal or greater than $1$, there is always at least $n$ 'special numbers' in $[a;a*k]$.

Comment: It may be helpful if you could tell us which definition of "special numbers" you have in mind.

Comment: Define $b$ as $b = az$. Then, all you know, is that interval $[b, kb] = [az, akz]$ constains at least $n$ speaciel numbers.

Comment: @Antoine but I can't find a counter example ( I'm looking just for some easy set of special numbers (other then primes) satisfying the condition there is exactly $n$ numbers in $[a,ak]$ but could not find it)

Comment: @Elaqqad What about powers of $2$ in combination with $k=2$? Or just any kind of special numbers $a_n$ that increase faster then linear.

Comment: @Antoine This is good example I think that you can provide an answer to this question

Comment: k=2, special to be even, a=1 , z=3.

Comment: If $z$ is a natural, $az$ is a natural, so your original condition says there will be at least $n$ special numbers in the interval $[az, akz]$, by plugging $az$ in for $a$.  You don't have any particular reason to expect more than that.

Comment: @RossMillikan But what if $z$ is a real ?

Comment: If $z$ is real, let it be $1.001$  Your assumption says there are at least $n$ special numbers in an interval.  The interval (in terms of naturals) shrinks:  for example $[1,2]$ becomes $[1.001,2.002]$ so only includes $2$, not $1$ as well.  You are also asking for at least $n$ special numbers, so now need $1.001n$ which (for smallish $n$) will require $n+1$

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the set of *special numbers* as $\{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, \dots\}$ and take $k = 2$.

For $a = 1$, the interval $[a,ak] = [1,2]$ contains two special numbers, for $a = 3$, the interval $[a, ak] = [3, 6]$ contain one special number.

Take $a = 1$. If the answer to you question was YES, then, for all $z\in\mathbb{N}$, the intervals of form $[az, azk] = [z, 2z]$ should contain at least $2$ special numbers, which is not the case.

---

Maybe, we should prove that all intervals $[a, 2a]$ contain at least one special number, otherwise the upper set is not a counterexample.

If there is a number $a\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $[a, 2a]$ does not contain a power of two, that it follows that $$2^m < a\quad \text{and} \quad 2a < 2^{m + 1}$$
for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$, which obviously leads to contradiction if we divide the second inequality by $2$.